# Dropdown, multiple values in dropdown

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I'm trying to make something for my hobby, and for that I was wondering on how to do it:

These are my input values:
[image: input]

And via dropdown you can choose one player and it autofills the other values:
[image: Dropdown]

But now in the dropdown it only shows the firstname, and it makes the selection based on that first name. so if I would have 2 players with the same first name I have a problem. Is there a way to make it check for first and lastname, and also show first and lastname in the dropdown.

Comment: How are you doing this? With a filter or with a form or activex control? Where is it referencing its list from?

Comment: At the moment with data validation set to list

Comment: And the selection calls a macro which fills in the rest? Or you have a worksheet_change event?

Comment: Vlookup is doing that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, this is sort of complicated, but I'll do my best to describe it.

First, you need a helper column that will combine first and last name (we'll put it in column J):

```
 J7=D7&" "&E7
```

drag it down. You can hide it if you want, but we will be referencing it.

Data validation list (in `K7`) will then be referenced to that list (in column J)

```
 =$J$7:$J$50
```

Now when you select from the drop down it will have both names. So we need to adjust the vlookup (column L) to an `index(match)` over two values (`*`), taking the values from the drop down -

```
 =INDEX($D$7:$I$50,MATCH(1,($D$7:$D$50=MID(K7,1,FIND(" ",K7)-1))*($E$7:$E$50=RIGHT(K7,LEN(K7)-FIND(" ",K7))),0),3)
```

**Note this is an array formula, so type it out and enter with CSE (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shft</kbd>+<kbd>Entr</kbd>)** - *it will show curly braces {} around it*

This will give you the 3rd column of the table for matching first and last name. Change the `3` at the end for each of the other columns in your table.

### Explanation of function:

Basically the `mid` function finds the space and gives the name before it and the `right` function finds the space and gives the name after it. Then it matches the first name to column D and the last name to column E and when both match, it returns the `3`rd column on the `row` that meets the conditions.

[see more about index(match) over multiple criteria](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/59482)

[learn more about array formulas](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-HA010342564.aspx)

Comment: Hmm, one small thing that doens't work here, if the name has multiple parts (like 'van den') it can not find the name

Comment: @Kiwi right, because the mid/right of the index(match) only looks for 2 blank spaces. If there are more blank spaces, it would need to count them to determine that, and then search appropriately. Right now, for "Mike Van Den" it will search for "Mike Den", I think. The easiest way to fix this is to make "van den" become "van_den".

Comment: I changed it to 'Van den,Mike' and letting it look for a ',' :) Still thx!

Comment: @Kiwi pretty clever :)